# How can multitasking experience be improved on Android tablets?

Tags: tablet, multitasking

I have a 10 inch Nexus tablet that I like to carry around while traveling. I can also connect it to a bluetooth keyboard, and this almost allows me to do everything a laptop can, but there are some major annoyances.

For example, I want to do web development while traveling. I can SSH into a remote server and edit the code there, and open the page on the Chrome app. However, Android only lets me have one app open at a time, so whenever I need to switch between two documents, it's very inefficient since I'm constantly closing and re-opening my apps.

I would like to use my Nexus 10 as my primary computer for working. How can my multitasking experience be improved?

Answer (score 2):

Android 7.x Nougat officially introduces multi-window. With this feature you can now run 2 apps side-by-side and drag the black interpolation bar to adjust the window size (3 tiers available).

[image]

With the aid of [Taskbar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farmerbb.taskbar) things get even better - with proper settings you get Windows-like task bar and resizable, movable multi-windows.

[image]

Ultimately though, without the ability to *natively* open multiple instances of one app, document abilities will be crippled to an extent. Wired video output is also absent, making presentation difficult, though if you have Miracast-compatible devices this isn't much of a problem.

Get started loading your Nexus 10 with Nougat-based custom ROMs by visiting [XDA-Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-10).

Do note that, due to the age of the tablet, Nougat won't run very snappily and you can't expect to multitask heavily.